# Add logging if ModelStats is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net

we're using the `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory` to standardize the layout of error responses. This works great.

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{                
    options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
    {
       var result = new BadRequestObjectResult(new BadRequestErrorResponse(context.ModelState));
       return result;
    };
});
```

But now the need has come up to also log these errors. How would we do that? Add the ILogger to this part of the code or create a custom Middleware/ActionFilter?

Addtitional Info, we use Seriloger:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // The initial "bootstrap" logger is able to log errors during start-up. It's completely replaced by the
    // logger configured in `UseSerilog()` below, once configuration and dependency-injection have both been
    // set up successfully.
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .CreateBootstrapLogger();
```

Left out the rest for brevity

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) => configuration
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
            .ReadFrom.Services(services)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        )
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the registered logger like this through the `context`:

```
var logger = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger>();
```

---

**UPDATE #1**
The [`UseSeriLog` registers an `ILoggerFactory`](https://andrewlock.net/adding-serilog-to-the-asp-net-core-generic-host/) rather than an explicit `ILogger`.

In that case you have to modify the above code like this:

```
var factory = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
var logger = factory.CreateLogger("InvalidModelState");
```

Comment: I tried that too but ILogger is not registered. Maybe because we use Seriloger. Do we have to explicitly add `ILogger` to the `IServiceCollection` even if DI on the controllers works?

Comment: @BluePalmTree How do you register the Seriloger?

Comment: I added the code to the question